# Code is giving an "Output is too large" when printing

Tags: python

here is the code=

```
def main():
   print("Enter your age: ")
   age= float(input())

   while age >= 0:

  if (age<= 2.00) :
    print("The guest whose age is",age,"is admitted without charge.")

  elif ((age>= 3.00) and (age<= 12.00)):
     print("A(n)",age," year old will cost $14.00 dollars for admission.")

  elif (age>=65.00) :
     print("A(n)",age,"year old will cost $18.00 dollars for admission.")

  else :
     print("A(n)",age,"year old will cost $23.00 dollars for admission.")



print("End of guest list")

main()
```

and here is the problem I am trying to solve:

Create a program that begins by reading the ages of all of the guests in a group from the user, with one age entered on each line. The user will enter -1 to indicate that there are no more guests in the group. Then your program should display the admission cost for the group with an appropriate message. The cost should be displayed using two decimal places. Use the following sample run for input and output messages.

Comment: how would i fix that?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.
Your posted code does not run due to a syntax error.

Comment: With the error repaired, your program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the prompt for input into the loop, otherwise age never changes within the `while`, creating an infinite loop.

```
def main():
   age = 1
   while age >= 0:
      print("Enter your age: ")
      age = float(input())

      if (age<= 2.00) :
         print("The guest whose age is",age,"is admitted without charge.")

      elif ((age>= 3.00) and (age<= 12.00)):
         print("A(n)",age," year old will cost $14.00 dollars for admission.")

      elif (age>=65.00) :
         print("A(n)",age,"year old will cost $18.00 dollars for admission.")

      else :
         print("A(n)",age,"year old will cost $23.00 dollars for admission.")



   print("End of guest list")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update `age` after its initial value and so the `while` loop continues forever, printing a line for each iteration.

You need to put a

```
age = float(input())
```

as the last line of the `while` loop.